# Passing a FLOAT value from a ratingBar from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parameter-passing

My Goal:

Hi guys, I will try my best to explain everything in detail.

I have two fragments and one main activity. What I am trying to to achieve is, have the user select a rating from the rating bar. Save that rating into a variable and display that value in the second fragment.

I have tried to achieve this using `Intent` and `Bundle` however it crashes my app on launch. In the app I have a swiping `tabLayout` which has two tabs. Tab one is linked to `OneFargment.java` and Tab two is linked to `TwoFragment.java`

I some what feel that the approach to using interfaces here will not work, as each fragment has a different layout. Any help or guidance will greatly be appreciated. If you guys need me to post the code for the XML files let me know.

`I am confused as how to recieve the values in my main activity, it seems that I need to define an ID to a fragment, but I dont have an id for fragment as each fragment has its own seperate layout file.`

Below is the code to all my files.

`OneFragment.java`

```
    package tanav.sharma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    OnFragmentSendVal vSendVal;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;
    private TextView txtRatingValue;

    public interface OnFragmentSendVal{
        public void onSentVal(float value);
    }

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            vSendVal = (OnFragmentSendVal)activity;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentSendVal");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tanav_image,
                container, false);

        addListenerOnRatingBar(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void addListenerOnRatingBar(View v) {

        ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        txtRatingValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);

        //if rating value is changed,
        //display the current rating value in the result (textview) automatically
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {



                float val = rating;
                vSendVal.onSentVal(val);
                //txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating));

            }
        });
    }



}
```

`TanavActivity.java`

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class TanavActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OneFragment.OnFragmentSendVal {

    RatingBar rb;
    TextView result;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_action_pro,
            R.drawable.ic_action_web
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tanav);


        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /**
         * This button is responsible for taking the user back
         * to the main activity. Preventing the user from pressing
         * the back key multiple times.
         */
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            int count_image = 0;
            int count_web = 0;
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int position = tab.getPosition();
                if(position == 0){

                    count_image = count_image + 1;
                    TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    counter.setText(Integer.toString(count_image));

                }else if(position == 1){
                    //count_web = count_web + 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                count_image = count_image + 1;
                TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
                counter.setText(Integer.toString(count_image));
            }
        });

    }



    private void setupTabIcons(){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.tanav));
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.sharma));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSentVal(float value) {

    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }


    /**
     * This function is responsible for prompting the user with a dialog box,
     * once the hit the back key on the app. Asking for confirmation if they,
     * really want to exit the app. If user selects Yes, the app will quit.
     * If the user selects cancel, the app will continue to run.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        CharSequence exit = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit);
        CharSequence exit_message = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.exit_message);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(exit)
                .setMessage(exit_message)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        TanavActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }


}
```

`TwoFragment.java`

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView lblResult;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sharma_web, container, false);

        String starRatings = getArguments().getString("stars");
        lblResult = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblResult);
        lblResult.setText(starRatings);

        return view;
    }




}
```

LOGCAT:

```
11-20 12:12:16.128 19867-19867/tanav.sharma E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: tanav.sharma, PID: 19867
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at tanav.sharma.TwoFragment.onCreateView(TwoFragment.java:31)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3111)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20221)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2687)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1932)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7564)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                at com.android.i
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer , you are using a new fragment instead of the one which has your bundle

Answer (score 2):

To pass the data from `OneFragment` to `TwoFragment` you have to implement the interaction using `interface` and you don't want this immediately so simply follow this link for [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and think of

> HeadlinesFragment as fragment one
>
> ArticleFragment as fragment
>
> two onListItemClick is your onRatingChanged

and replace `int` values with appropriate `float` parameters and methods

Comment: "Use `floatextra` instead of `stingextra`"... Just upvote my answer and cite it instead of hastily trying to copy it, it saves you the embarrassment of referencing non-existant and typo laden methods. Watch I'll give you an upvote for finding a valid problem too.

Comment: When i change i.getStringExtra to i.getFloatExtra it gives me the following error:::: getFloatExtra (String, float) in intent cannot be applied to string.

Comment: @TanavSharma you have to do use put and get float extra at appropriate places

Comment: Also, when i change the new TwoFragment to twoFragment, it says Method call expected. what does that mean?

Comment: I am not experienced in Java programming yet

Comment: Read me answer more carefully `float var = i.getFloatExtra(...` not `String var = i...`

Comment: @TanavSharma update your answer with the new issues your facing

Comment: @Sam yes with the line `"float val = i.getFloatExtra(...` gives me that error. How ever i am adding my other confusion also, in nexxt comment

Comment: Do i need to use the following line `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new OneFragment()).commit();` almost all tutorials i have seen on youtube are using this line of code. And i cannot use it, as I have not clue what `R.id.container` is reffering to.

Comment: @TanavSharma you don't have to change anything here if you son't require `stars` value in your `onefragment` otherwise do the same bundle code for first fragment (create an object of fragment one and set argument ) use it as `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, oneFragment).commit(); `

Comment: I am updating my code above, please let me know if i am on the right track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128584/discussion-between-tanav-sharma-and-pavneet-singh).

Comment: sam editing takes time and you posted your answer while i was at the first edit and i appreciate your efforts that you find an issue +1  though i knew it is NEP so the other updates were on their way

Answer (score 1):

> however it crashes my app on launch.

If your app crashes always post the logcat, it tells everyone *exactly* where the error occurs.

---

You probably have multiple errors but I see one logic fault right from the start.

You store the value as a `float`:

```
float val = rating;
...
i.putExtra("star",val);
```

But you try to use `.getStringExtra()` to retrieve it...

```
String vals = i.getStringExtra("star");
```

Remember `val` is a **`float`** not a **`String`**, use the appropriate getter:
[`getFloatExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getFloatExtra(java.lang.String,%20float)) instead.

```
float val = i.getFloatExtra("star");
```

Comment: i will add the logcat, i forgot to do so :(

Comment: @TanavSharma Pavneet is leading you down the right path.  The logcat tells you that `getArguments()` in `TwoFragment.onCreateView()` returns `null` so you cannot use `.getString("stars")` on a `null` object.  You need to actually pass `TwoFragment` the `float` value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers here, for a more flexible way, try using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or staic variables. Using these, you can store the variables and retrieve them when needed, instead of having to start an activity immediately.